# Physiological changes necessary to scale an insect's size up while maintaining a catapult jumping mechanism and jump/body ratio?

Tags: biology, creature-design, science-fiction, aliens, xenobiology

I understand that one does not simply scale up the smallest of creatures to the size of megafauna without violating basic physiological constraints like the square/cube law, among others; so what *would* have to take place to take a grasshopper and enlarge it to the relative size of a grizzly bear (in terms of 3D space) and preserve its catapult jumping system?

The only thing that need remain in terms of 'grasshopper-ness, or cricket-ness' is the catapult jumping system, and preferably a frightening insectoid appearance. It need not look at all like our starting-creatures.

- Higher oxygen content in the air?
- Sturdier body-plan (i.e. thicker carapace? Different materials? Wider joints/legs?)
- Bird-bone-esque adaptation of weight to power? Or is this irrelevant with mostly slow-twitch muscle at the play in the catapult system?

I'm trying to think through a creature that relies on jumping and mechanoreception to hunt prey, and is somewhat frightening to behold.

Comment: You have a problem here, it's that the square/cube law isn't so much a _"basic physiological constraint"_  as a basic physics constraint, no physiological changes will give you the same _"jump/body" ratio"_.

Comment: @Pelinore what's that `square/cube law` in the context? The pure mechanical things scale linearly just fine, this is how you get your bridges while only measuring the compression modulus of a small cube of steel.

Comment: @Adrian no they really don't scale linearly just fine, try dropping an ant from 100 feet, now try dropping a perfectly scale but giant 1 ton ant from the same height, now tell me these things scale just fine again.

Comment: @Pelinore can you provide citations that document those laws? Or is just the fact that nobody has yet observed a 'giant 1 ton ant' so we can handwave something in?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi This is stuff you should know from secondary school, Google it

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Its a pretty simple law. The cross sectional area of a muscle gets squared, which is proportional to strength. The weight it needs to lift gets cubed (volume)  because real things aren't purely 2D. So your square your strength and cube the weight you need to lift. So as you increase the size, the weight will naturally increase faster than your strength and lower all strength related ratios.

Comment: @Shadowzee thanks, a pertinent answer.

Comment: @Pelinore You're right. Drop a flea off a building, its own terminal velocity leaves it unharmed. Drop a grizzly off.. well. But what if the creature evolved to to leap rather low to the ground -- like a long jump -- and roll through its inertia? Essentially, hitting its prey like a comet? Require force-generation notwithstanding, would that not solve deceleration and impact injuries?

Comment: Nope just won't work, sorry, see @Shadowzee's summary of the square cube law, the bigger it gets the more muscle it needs to achieve the same distance jump (note: the same distance proportional to its body size is further than that) & the more muscle it has the bigger it gets, even the most exotic of materials won't be enough to fully get around that.

Comment: You might play with the environment (things like air density, gravity, planet spin to counter gravity etc) but those things all work equally for every other animal so it's jump ability then becomes nothing special .. no with even moderately 'firm' science fiction there's no real way around it .. other than handwavium mined from the very softest of sci-fi ore just saying 'it's magic' is essentially your only option.

Comment: @Pelinore `Nope just won't work, sorry` I'm not quite convinced - it's too simplistic. The force may be proportional with the area of muscles, but the distance/height of the jump is proportional with the energy = mechanical work of the muscles. Which just happens to be proportional with the force*limb-length - i.e. it will take longer to execute the jump (accelerate to the final velocity). So work ~ square*linear => back into cubic. Assuming the same avg body density, the result should maintain the proportionality. There may be other things at play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with:

1. a composite exoskeleton - layers of highly compressive-resistant materials between layers of elastic ones; or highly elastic on compression and high tensile will do the same - is something needed to be elastic and diffusive (spread the energy/tension over higher area) enough to mellow the take-off/landing shocks while still conserving/converting as much energy as possible (e.g landing recover some energy required for the next jump).
   Two YouTube down-to-Earth-engineering clips that deal with composites for hardening and elasticity: [fiber glass strengthening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Pc-Sd_J26E) and [core composites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiS8ArzEA58)
2. elastic and tough "tendons" that allow [storing mechanical energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping#Power_amplification_through_stored_energy) to be used in the jump - and maybe replenished over a longer time. That is, it would be easier if the creature doesn't keep kangaroo-style hopping but taking some time to prepare for the jump (like grass-hoppers do)